# reversing the cutoff values in R using ROCR packge

Tags: r, roc

I am using a confusion matrix to create a ROC Curve. The problem I have is the cutoff values are revered. How to do I put them in ascending order?

```
pred <- prediction(predictions =c(rep(5,19),rep(7,24),rep(9,40),rep(10,42)), labels =
c(rep(0,18),rep(1,1),rep(0,7),rep(1,17),rep(0,4),rep(1,36),rep(0,3),rep(1,39)))
perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf,colorize=TRUE)
abline(0,1,col='red')
x = c(0.09375,0.21875,0.43750)
y = c(0.4193548,0.8064516,0.9892473)
points(x , y , col="red", pch=19)
text(x , y+0.03, labels= c("9","7","5"), col="red", pch=19)
predictions = c(rep(5,19),rep(7,24),rep(9,40),rep(10,42))
labels = c(rep(0,18),rep(1,1),rep(0,7),rep(1,17),rep(0,4),rep(1,36),rep(0,3),rep(1,39))
auc(predictions,labels)
```

Comment: What do you mean by reversed?

Comment: The cut-off values are 5,7,9. when it is displayed it is displaying as 9,7,5